# Cisco AnyConnect not connecting

Tags: vpn, cisco

Cisco AnyConnect used to work on my laptop.  Now when it starts, the dialog pops up for a moment, but the VPN location dropdown and Connect button are disabled.  Then the dialog goes away and no connection is made.  Internal support said my profile is probably the problem and that I should re-image the machine, which is not a viable option.  I've completely uninstalled it, including removing left over registry entries and temp files.  After reinstalling, it still does the same thing.  Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had already done a ton of research and posting here was a last resort.  But I decided to check the event logs and stumbled on this informational entry:

```
Function: CCertStore::GetCertificates
File: Certificates\CertStore.cpp
Line: 220
Ignoring client certificate because it does not contain the required EKU extension. Certificate details:
Store: Microsoft User, Subject: OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, CN=*.cdn.optimizely.com, Common Name: *.cdn.optimizely.com, Dept: Created by http://www.fiddler2.com, Company: DO_NOT_TRUST, Issuer: OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, Not Valid Before: Sep 26 12:00:37 2018 GMT, Not Valid After: Dec 25 12:00:37 2021 GMT, Serial: 7C0FA44D30EA72984C817EF8688A10C0, SHA1 Fingerprint: 47B8A251051905D0DE8C1B15F47C045FECC41290, DNS Name: *.cdn.optimizely.com
```

As well as other error entries about cert issues, although the Information entry was the only one that mentioned Fiddler.

I checked the certificate manager and all of my personal certificates had been created during Fiddler use.  I deleted all of them, and then restarted Cisco AnyConnect and it worked fine.

Comment: what is fiddler ??

Comment: Fiddler is basically a man in the middle tool used to troubleshoot HTTP/S calls: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler